# How to create a nested menu using CSV file content

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to use a CSV file for creating a webpage menu structure.

Can anyone please help me to create a nested menu in Jacascript using the given CSV structure?

The columns are: Level, Menu name, URL

```
0;"Service";
1;"Service 1";"http://some-url-1.com"
1;"Service 2";"http://some-url-2.com"
0;"Sales";
1;"Sales 1";"http://some-url-3.com"
1;"Sales 2";"http://some-url-4.com"
1;"Sales 3";
2;"Sales 3 Sub 1";"http://some-ulr-5.com";
0;"Development";"http://some-url-6.com"
0;"Internet";
1;"Internet 1";
2;"Internet 1 Sub 1";"http://some-url-7.com";
```

The first column shows the menu levels.
0- root level
1- first level
2- second level

Also the order of the menu items should be exactly as given in the CSV file.

Comment: I think you are asking for too much here. You should try to write some code first, then show what you have done, explain what you want to do and what isn't working. But right now you are posting a CSV file (why not JSON?) and ask to give you the code.

Comment: I am receiving a CSV file. But I can convert the CSV as JSON also. But still I am curious to know the best approach to generate a menu structure.

Comment: Start with creating single-level menu and then add another level, and then, if something won't work - raise a hand.

Comment: Best apporach is not use parsing `Internet 1 Sub 1` as child of `Sub` which is a child of `Internet`. Best approach is to use clear structured config. Try JSON with proper nesting and w/o need in parsing.

Comment: I can imagine how JSON for this CSV should be. But for clarification, can you post the JSON obj structure you are getting equivalent to this CSV ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code, this works for more than 3 levels. I commented out ajax call and converted your csv data to string for testing, because SO editor won't get the csv file, you can use ajax and get csv content in your project.

note: i assumed the level/depth of menu item increases by one, but can decrease by more than one.

```js
$(function () {

            var data_str = '0;\"Service\";\n1;\"Service 1\";\"http:\/\/some-url-1.com\"\n1;\"Service 2\";\"http:\/\/some-url-2.com\"\n0;\"Sales\";\n1;\"Sales 1\";\"http:\/\/some-url-3.com\"\n1;\"Sales 2\";\"http:\/\/some-url-4.com\"\n1;\"Sales 3\";\n2;\"Sales 3 Sub 1\";\"http:\/\/some-ulr-5.com\";\n3;\"Sales 3 Sub 1 Sub 1\";\"http:\/\/some-ulr-5.com\";\n4;\"Sales 3 Sub 1 Sub 1 Sub 1\";\"http:\/\/some-ulr-5.com\";\n0;\"Development\";\"http:\/\/some-url-6.com\"\n0;\"Internet\";\n1;\"Internet 1\";\n2;\"Internet 1 Sub 1\";\"http:\/\/some-url-7.com\";';
            CreateMenu();
            function CreateMenu() {
                var lines = data_str.replace(/"/g, '').split(/\r\n|\n/);
                var menu_html = '';
                var levels = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    var menu_item = lines[i].split(';')
                    levels.push(parseInt(menu_item[0]));
                }
                var parent = -1;
                for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    var menu_item = lines[i].split(';')
                    var link = "";
                    if (levels[i] == 0) {
                        link = menu_item[1];
                    }
                    else {
                        link = '<a href="' + menu_item[2] + '"> ' + menu_item[1] + '</a>';
                    }
                    if (levels[i] < parent) {
                        var prefix = '</ul></li><li>';
                        for (var j = 1; j < parent - levels[i]; j++) {
                            prefix = '</ul></li>' + prefix;
                        }
                        menu_html += prefix + link

                    }
                    if (levels[i] == parent) {
                        menu_html += '</li><li>' + link
                    }
                    if (levels[i] > parent) {
                        menu_html += '<ul><li>' + link
                    }
                    parent = levels[i];

                } 
                $(menu_html).appendTo($('#menu_parent'));
            }
            //$.ajax({
            //    type: "GET",
            //    url: "data.csv",
            //    dataType: "text",
            //    success: function (data) {
            //        data_str = data;
            //        CreateMenu();
            //    }
            //});
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="menu_parent"></div>
```

Comment: It looks fine with some adjustments in the html tags closing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery library to build your custom menu. Moreover, you can adjust custom css based on your element's class or attributes. here is a sample menu for your case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var strcsv = '0; "Service";\r\n1; "Service 1"; "http://some-url-1.com"\r\n1; "Service 2"; "http://some-url-2.com"\r\n0; "Sales";\r\n1; "Sales 1"; "http://some-url-3.com"\r\n1; "Sales 2"; "http://some-url-4.com"\r\n1; "Sales 3";\r\n2; "Sales 3 Sub 1"; "http://some-ulr-5.com";\r\n0; "Development"; "http://some-url-6.com"\r\n0; "Internet";\r\n1; "Internet 1";\r\n2; "Internet 1 Sub 1"; "http://some-url-7.com";';
        function CreateMenu(csvString, dvpanel) {
            var items = csvString.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                var spliteditem = items[i].split(/\;/);
                var lvl = spliteditem[0];
                var title = spliteditem[1];
                var url = (spliteditem.length < 3) ? null : spliteditem[2];

                var $holderdv;
                if (lvl == "0") $holderdv = $(dvpanel);
                else {
                    $holderdv = $(dvpanel).find("div[menuitem-level='" + (lvl - 1) + "']").filter(function () { return $(this).attr("menuitem-index") < i; }).last();
                }
                $holderdv
                    .append($("<div menuitem-level='" + lvl + "' menuitem-index='" + i + "'>")
                        .append($("<a href='" + (url == null ? "#" : url) + "'>")
                            .append($("<span>")
                                .html(title))))

            }
        }
        $(function () { CreateMenu(strcsv, $("#MenuPanel")); });
    </script>
    <style>
        div[menuitem-level='0'] {
            margin: 5px;
            background-color: #eaeaea;
        }

        div[menuitem-level='1'] {
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #d1d1d1;
        }

        div[menuitem-level='2'] {
            margin: 30px;
            background-color: #a5a5a5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MenuPanel"></div>       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using SlickGrid for this. It is super-easy to use and is awesome performance-wise. Plus, your case, you can create a tree-like structure which you can easily collapse/expand/filter. Check [this sample](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html) out.